# The most efficient way to read data from a sensor and write to a file

Tags: dart, file-io, bluetooth-lowenergy, signal-processing, circular-buffer

I am working on a system which is capable of:

1. Reading data from a Bluetooth sensor
2. Converting data into int16
3. Writing data in a .bin file
4. Displaying data on a mobile application screen

The problem that I have, since file reading and writing operations are designed as 'async', I am missing to write some data that is transfered by Bluetooth device into the file. I guess I am receiving data faster than I am writing it into the file.

The solution that I got so far is to create a circular buffer (even maybe two, 1 to write into .bin file and 1 to display on the mobile screen with a window of 10-seconds). That way, even though the writing operation will be slower, I guess I will not lose any data and monitoring might be done live(?).

Is there a more efficient way to quickly write the data received by a sensor to a file without losing it?

Comment: "I am missing some data that is transfered by Bluetooth device". Sound like you have some badly designed logic since that sounds really strange. You should get the events as a `Stream` which you can then directly pipe into a file (maybe after some needed mapping and transformations which can be part of the pipe).

Comment: Also, I find it very unlikely that you can get bluetooth events faster that you can write to disk if you are making proper use of the Dart file API (so using write buffering and does not flush for each event). I would guess your current code gets one event, open the file, write to the file, close the file and flush the file? If so, that explains the bad performance. :)

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you for your answer. I edited this part of my message, thinking that it might be misleading. In fact, Bluetooth sensor works fine and it is sending me all data that I need. I verified this. The issue is, I am calling "async write await" structure on the data that I want to write into a file. In some cases it writes, and it some cases it doesn't. I thought it might be because of this async structure which is taking some time. I search and indeed, async is taking time in Dart.

Comment: Yeah, but you should setup a `StreamController` and sends the events into that. You can then have a `Stream` with multiple mapping steps and then pipe that into a file.

Comment: @julemand101 Indeed, "taking the current directory, creating a new file if it doesn't exist and writing into it" calls are happening under the same Widget. You are right. Being a beginner, I didn't consider this. Thank you very much, I will modify the structure.

Comment: If you want to log every event to a file and then keep the last 100 events in memory, you can use a `Queue` to quickly insert data in one end and remove data in the other end: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-collection/Queue-class.html . (if you keep the size the same it is basically a circular buffer).

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you very much, I will check it out. In fact, I was using the same structure given here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files. I just didn't think it would slow it down this much.

Comment: @julemand101 Hello, I have progressed in my code using your feedback, although I encounter new problems. I would very much appreciate your answer if you have some time for it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70847965/12256972?sem=2